# How to generate training samples for LSTM?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, keras, deep-learning

I have 100 invidual time series (units - index) within the dataframe below and want to train LSTM to predict the target ('RUL').

My data look like:

```
train.head()

cycles  os1 os2 sm2 sm3 sm4 sm6 sm7 sm8 sm9 sm11    sm12    sm13    sm14    sm15    sm17    sm20    sm21    RUL
unit                                                                            
1   1   -0.0007 -0.0004 641.82  1589.70 1400.60 21.61   554.36  2388.06 9046.19 47.47   521.66  2388.02 8138.62 8.4195  392 39.06   23.4190 191
1   2   0.0019  -0.0003 642.15  1591.82 1403.14 21.61   553.75  2388.04 9044.07 47.49   522.28  2388.07 8131.49 8.4318  392 39.00   23.4236 190
1   3   -0.0043 0.0003  642.35  1587.99 1404.20 21.61   554.26  2388.08 9052.94 47.27   522.42  2388.03 8133.23 8.4178  390 38.95   23.3442 189
1   4   0.0007  0.0000  642.35  1582.79 1401.87 21.61   554.45  2388.11 9049.48 47.13   522.86  2388.08 8133.83 8.3682  392 38.88   23.3739 188
1   5   -0.0019 -0.0002 642.37  1582.85 1406.22 21.61   554.00  2388.06 9055.15 47.28   522.19  2388.04 8133.80 8.4294  393 38.90   23.4044 187
```

The dimensionality is:

```
# Training data
X.shape
(20631, 18)


# Labels/targets
y.shape
(20631,)
```

So far, I've tried:

```
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator

data_gen = TimeseriesGenerator(X, y,
                               length=10, sampling_rate=2,
                               batch_size=2)

# Model
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=128, activation='relu', dropout=0.25, input_shape=(18,1))) # Input layer
model.add(Dense(units=1)) # Output layer
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='rmae')
#model.fit(x, y, epochs=30, batch_size=7)
model.fit_generator(data_gen, steps_per_epoch=len(data_gen), epochs=100)
```

...which yields:

> ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 5 to array axis with
> dimension 18

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model waits for and input (x) array/sequence with length of 18 (`input_shape=(18,1)`). But it gets one with length of 5. You shoud change the parameters of `TimeseriesGenerator` to `length=18` and `sampeling_rate=1` maybe, to generate imputs with length of 18.

Comment: I have marked the answer as correct, tho I think I still need to separate the 100 time series somehow.

Comment: So, can you clarify what belongs to one time series? It's still not totally clear. There are 20 columns in your (pandas?) dataframe. The last one is the RUL, what u'd like to predict. But what about the other columns? Is one row corresponds to one entry/serie?

Comment: Actually for me it seems like the time series are in the columns. (So there are maybe 18 different series.)

Comment: The dataset is 100 engines with sensor readings until failure. Each index number is one engine. There's a number of cycles and it's inverse function expressed as RUL (target). The thing is, each engine has got it's own time series.

Comment: Still didn't get it what's your dataset actually looks like. (What are the columns [cycles, os1, os2 etc.] and rows.) Anyway this generator waits a timeserie with one or more dimensions, with one target value for each time step. (Like a multi dimensionat function _f(x, y, z, ...)_ where _f, x, y_ and _z_ are datapoints in a timeserie.) So I think in your case it would mean, that for every single timestep there is one measured value for every engine and there is only one target value (RUL) for all of the engines. (Or there is one target value for each engines at each timestep.)

Comment: And the generator returns with X-y pairs where the X are some part of the time serie, and y is the target value in the "next" time step.

Comment: This might help, if you didn't find yet. [link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-use-the-timeseriesgenerator-for-time-series-forecasting-in-keras/)